# How can find this limit? $\lim_{x\to-∞}(\sqrt{x^2+6x}-\sqrt{x^2-2x})$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to-∞}(\sqrt{x^2+6x}-\sqrt{x^2-2x})$$
plugging in infinity gives infinity - infinity, what kind of manipulation can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a subtle point when you algebraically manipulate the expression (this can be seen in several of the given answers): since you can assume that $x<0$ (actually $x<-6$ in order that the expression is meaningful), you have to remember that
$$
\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x
$$
So
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-∞}(\sqrt{x^2+6x}-\sqrt{x^2-2x})
&=\lim_{x\to-∞}\frac{(x^2+6x)-(x^2-2x)}{\sqrt{x^2+6x}+\sqrt{x^2-2x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-∞}\frac{8x}{\sqrt{x^2(1+6/x)}+\sqrt{x^2(1-2/x)}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-∞}\frac{8x}{|x|\bigl(\sqrt{(1+6/x)}+\sqrt{(1-2/x)}\,\bigr)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-∞}\frac{8}{-\bigl(\sqrt{(1+6/x)}+\sqrt{(1-2/x)}\,\bigr)}\\
&=-4
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Exploit the identity:
$$\sqrt{x^2+6x}-\sqrt{x^2-2x} = \frac{8x}{\sqrt{x^2+6x}+\sqrt{x^2-2x}} = \frac{8x}{2|x|+O(1)}.$$

Comment: Beat me to it! +1

Comment: I am stuck on the third step how did u turn the square roots to 2x + 0(1)?

Comment: $$\sqrt{x^2+Ax} = x\sqrt{1+\frac{A}{x}} = x\cdot\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right) = x+O(1).$$

Comment: To be more precise, $$x+\frac{A}{2}\geq\sqrt{x^2+Ax}\geq x+\frac{A}{2}-\frac{A^2}{8x}$$ by a similar technique.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you did, on the calculator square root of squaredx + ax is not equal to x, I see that you took x^2 common then got it out as x what did u do next?

Comment: Ehm, the function is negative when $x<k$ (for some $k$); how can the limit be positive?

Comment: @egreg: you are right, now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Set $-\dfrac1x=h$ to

$$x^2+6x=\frac{1-6h}{h^2}\implies\sqrt{x^2+6x}=\frac{\sqrt{1-6h}}{\sqrt{h^2}}$$

and as $x\to-\infty,h\to0^+$ and $h>0,\sqrt{h^2}=+h$

So we have
 $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+6x}-\sqrt{x^2-2x})=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1-6h}-\sqrt{1+2h}}h$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{1-6h-(1+2h)}{h(\sqrt{1-6h}+\sqrt{1+2h})}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{x^2+6x}=\sqrt{x^2+6x+9-9}=\sqrt{(x+3)^2-9}\approx |x|+3,\text{ as }x\to-\infty$$
$$\sqrt{x^2-2x}=\sqrt{x^2-2x+1-1}=\sqrt{(x-1)^2-1}\approx |x|-1,\text{ as }x\to-\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ \sqrt{x^2+6x}-\sqrt{x^2-2x} = \frac{8x}{\sqrt{x^2+6x}+\sqrt{x^2-2x}}, $$so our answer is the limit of the above as $ x \to -\infty $. But note that $ \sqrt {x^2 + 6x} + \sqrt {x^2 - 2x} \sim \mathcal{O}(2x) $, so the answer is $\frac{8}{2}=\boxed{4}$.

Comment: Really? A negative function has positive limit?

Comment: The issue is that $\sqrt{x^2+6x}+\sqrt{x^2-2x}=2|x|+O(1)$.

Answer (score -1):

To conclude this The answer is actually -4 , because you can do this step

[image: and the answer is clearly 4.]

Comment: No, the limit is $-4$.